# passing a function reference in python

Tags: python

Ok, So I am seeing something weird and I think I misunderstood how to pass functions around in python..

```
class Foo:
  def execute(self, **kwargs):
    print "self is ", self # <foo.Foo object at 0x1012948d0>
    features = {func_name: feature_func(kwargs, arg=arg)for func_name, 
                              feature_func in Foo.ALGORITHMS.items()}

  def func1(self, **kwargs):
     print "self is " , self # prints {}
     self._funchelp()

  def __funchelp(self):
     # pass


  ALGORITHMS = {'func1': func1}
```

So, what I am not getting is why is self printing to be an empty dictionary??

```
features = {func_name: feature_func(kwargs, arg=arg)for func_name, 
                              feature_func in Foo.ALGORITHMS.items()}
```

Something gets messed up above

And then

self._funchelp()
Returns `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_Foo__funchelp'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you need to include `self` as the first argument to `feature_func` in your dict comprehension.  Also, you need to put the `**` in front of kwargs.  You may also need to set the 'arg' key on `kwargs` as follows to avoid some kind of argument error.  Not sure about that though:

```
kwargs['arg'] = 123
features = {func_name: feature_func(self, **kwargs) for func_name, 
                          feature_func in Foo.ALGORITHMS.items()}
```

The weird error is probably because you're trying to access `_funchelp` as an attribute on an empty dict object.  Furthermore, your function is defined as `__funchelp` with two underscores, which could get [mangled](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) by python because of the way it handles double underscore attributes internally.  I think `_funchelp` must be a typo because I don't think it would be mangling the name if that was really what was in your code.

Comment: this is correct, you're not instantiating an instance of the class. either make classmethods or instantiate an instance.